# Getting the center and boundaries of cell of raster object in R

Tags: raster, r

### Raster visualization

[image: visual representation of the raster file]

### Raster information

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 81808, 37369, 3057083152  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0001843661, 0.0001843661  (x, y)
extent     : 119.7351, 126.6247, 4.554176, 19.6368  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : /path/to/raster.tif 
names      : raster 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

Information derived from R/RStudio

### Objective

[image: zoomed-in visual representation of the raster file]
Above is the zoomed-in visualization of the same raster. Given some **LatLng** values with *7-to-8-decimal places* (white marker), I think there should be a way to find the **center** and **boundaries** locations (black markers) of a certain cell/pixel.

I tried the functions [`cellFromXY()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-13/topics/cellFrom) and [`xyFromCell()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-13/topics/xyFromCell) but got no luck because they were just returning the same values like so:

```r
raster.data <- raster( "/path/to/raster.tif" ) 
given.point <- c( 123.17987768 , 12.09548919 )
cell.target <- cellFromXY( raster.data , given.point )
benchmark.point <- xyFromCell( raster.data , cell.target )
```

Both the `given.point` and `benchmark.point` returned the same values and can not be used this way to get the center values. Which puts me to the question...

How to get the center and boundaries of a cell of a raster object using R?

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate those yourself,
something like this should work, since you have the coordinate of the cell.

```
library(rts)
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")

r1 <- raster(f) 
nc = r1@ncols
nr = r1@nrows
d = r1@extent
point = c(15.5,20.3)
cellCol = colFromX(r1, 15.5)
cellRow = rowFromY(r1, 20.3)

xlen = d@xmax-d@xmin
ylen = d@ymax-d@ymin
cellXSize = xlen/d@xmax
cellYSize = ylen/d@ymax
XMinCoord = (cellCol-1)*cellXSize
YMinCoord = (ylen-(cellRow-1))*cellYSize
XMaxCoord = (cellCol)*cellXSize
YMaxCoord = (ylen-(cellRow))*cellYSize
bounds = c(XMinCoord,XMaxCoord,YMinCoord,YMaxCoord)
centerX = XMinCoord+(cellXSize*0.5)
centerY = YMinCoord-(cellYSize*0.5)
center = c(centerX,centerY)

plot(r1)
points(x=15.5,y=20.3,col="white", bg = "white", pch=16 )
points(x=centerX,y=centerY,col="black", bg = "black", pch=16 )
points(x=XMinCoord,y=YMinCoord,col="black",  pch=22 )
points(x=XMinCoord,y=YMaxCoord,col="black",  pch=22 )
points(x=XMaxCoord,y=YMaxCoord,col="black",  pch=22 )
points(x=XMaxCoord,y=YMinCoord,col="black",  pch=22 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's test your statement that your method doesn't work. First make a simple tiny raster:

```
raster.data <- raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)


given.point <- c(0.2345, 0.4567)
cell.target <- cellFromXY( raster.data , given.point )
benchmark.point <- xyFromCell( raster.data , cell.target )
```

and I see that the benchmark point is not the same as the given point:

```
> given.point
[1] 0.2345 0.4567
> benchmark.point
         x   y
[1,] 0.125 0.5
```

and if I plot them I can see it is doing it correctly:

[image]

So there seems to be nothing wrong with your method. You've not shown us the output values for your test point so we can't tell if you really don't get a difference or if you aren't seeing it because you aren't seeing enough decimal points or if your test point is actually on a cell centre.